# How to force an application (Brave) to inhibit shorcuts (so to capture ALT-TAB) in Wayland?

Tags: wayland

I'm using Brave with PiKVM, which is a software allowing to connect from remote to PC. PiKVM has a web interface with remote desktop functionalities. If I go full-screen, system (Gnome+Wayland) asks if I want to allow Brave to inhibit shortcuts, which is fine. I'd like to force this behaviour (inhibiting shortcuts) also when Brave is not full-screen. Is there a way to force this from command line?